# Can I detect the *first* time a user has logged into an app using the facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook

Using the latest facebook sdk 3.1, I open a session requesting permissions using:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                 }];
```

My sessionStateChanged method looks like this:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                        state:(FBSessionState)state
                        error:(NSError *)error
{

    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // handle successful login
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // handle failed login
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way inside sessionStateChanged to distinguish if this is the *first* time the user has ever logged in (i.e. they have never before given us permission for this particular app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to know if this is the user's first time authorizing the application or not. Your best option is to track within your own application if they have logged in before.

Comment: thanks hukir - did you see this documented somewhere? btw what i could analyze from the data returned after a successful fb login there is no way to determine this.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. I think there is no way to determine when a user has logged in. So I think we have to user old facebook in which we need to implement FBSessionDelegate mehthods (fbDidLogin etc). But once i have done authorization and integration from new sdk , would i have to do this process again with old facebook sdk???

Comment: If you look at the FBSession Reference (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession), among the rest of the reference, you'll see there isn't anything about which login it is. Also, you can look at the Server Side Login Guide (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/), which tells you more about how the actual login flow woks. If you look at the data passed around, all you get is the relevant login info. The data is the same if it is the first or 100th login.